# Mul4 deployment error org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file

Tags: deployment, mule4, saxparseexception

I have a mule application that have all global configurations under a file name shared shared-configurations.xml. When I deploy the application I am getting the error below. Its on-prem mule CE. The build is running fine on local but on server it is failing. XML validated for no errors. Any help here is much appreciated.

```
ERROR 2021-11-23 20:08:[Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.application.DefaultMuleApplication: Error loading: shared-configurations.xml, Premature end of file.
    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1473) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1014) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at org.mule.runtime.dsl.internal.xml.parser.MuleDocumentLoader.loadDocument(MuleDocumentLoader.java:80) ~[mule-module-dsl-api-1.2.0.jar:?]
        at org.mule.runtime.dsl.api.xml.parser.XmlConfigurationDocumentLoader.loadDocument(XmlConfigurationDocumentLoader.java:134) ~[mule-module-dsl-api-1.2.0.jar:?]
        at org.mule.runtime.dsl.api.xml.parser.XmlConfigurationProcessor.lambda$recursivelyResolveConfigFiles$3(XmlConfigurationProcessor.java:72) ~[mule-module-dsl-api-1.2.0.jar:?]
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1384) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:485) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
        at org.mule.runtime.dsl.api.xml.parser.XmlConfigurationProcessor.recursivelyResolveConfigFiles(XmlConfigurationProcessor.java:67) ~[mule-module-dsl-api-1.2.0.jar:?]
        at org.mule.runtime.dsl.api.xml.parser.XmlConfigurationProcessor.processXmlConfiguration(XmlConfigurationProcessor.java:52) ~[mule-module-dsl-api-1.2.0.jar:?]
        at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.MuleArtifactContext.createApplicationModel(MuleArtifactContext.java:260) ~[mule-module-spring-config-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.MuleArtifactContext.<init>(MuleArtifactContext.java:230) ~[mule-module-spring-config-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.MuleArtifactContext.<init>(MuleArtifactContext.java:190) ~[mule-module-spring-config-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doCreateApplicationContext(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:179) ~[mule-module-spring-config-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createApplicationContext(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:159) ~[mule-module-spring-config-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:133) ~[mule-module-spring-config-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.core.api.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:53) ~[mule-core-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.core.api.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:84) ~[mule-core-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.config.api.dsl.artifact.SpringArtifactConfigurationProcessor.createArtifactContext(SpringArtifactConfigurationProcessor.java:50) ~[mule-module-spring-config-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.artifact.ArtifactContextBuilder$1.configure(ArtifactContextBuilder.java:452) ~[mule-module-deployment-model-impl-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.core.api.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:65) ~[mule-core-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.core.api.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:187) ~[mule-core-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.core.api.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:59) ~[mule-core-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.artifact.ArtifactContextBuilder.lambda$build$2(ArtifactContextBuilder.java:487) ~[mule-module-deployment-model-impl-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ExceptionUtils.tryExpecting(ExceptionUtils.java:227) ~[mule-core-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:915) ~[mule-core-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:879) ~[mule-core-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.artifact.ArtifactContextBuilder.build(ArtifactContextBuilder.java:398) ~[mule-module-deployment-model-impl-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.application.DefaultMuleApplication.doInit(DefaultMuleApplication.java:221) ~[mule-module-deployment-model-impl-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:190) ~[mule-module-deployment-model-impl-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.lambda$withContextClassLoader$9(ClassUtils.java:860) ~[mule-core-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ExceptionUtils.tryExpecting(ExceptionUtils.java:227) [mule-core-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:915) [mule-core-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:879) [mule-core-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:859) [mule-core-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.artifact.DeployableArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(DeployableArtifactWrapper.java:140) [mule-module-deployment-model-impl-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.artifact.DeployableArtifactWrapper.init(DeployableArtifactWrapper.java:83) [mule-module-deployment-model-impl-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArtifactDeployer.doInit(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:63) [mule-module-deployment-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:28) [mule-module-deployment-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:475) [mule-module-deployment-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:527) [mule-module-deployment-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:226) [mule-module-deployment-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:411) [mule-module-deployment-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:56) [mule-module-deployment-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:241) [mule-module-deployment-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.run(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:312) [mule-module-deployment-4.2.1.jar:4.2.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_292]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [?:1.8.0_292]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_292]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [?:1.8.0_292]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_292]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_292]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_292]
    INFO  2021-11-23 20:08:20,165 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] [event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.impl.internal.artifact.AbstractDeployableArtifact: Application 'prc-platform-services-1.0.0-mule-application' never started, nothing to dispose of
```

Comment: Please share shared-configurations.xml.

Comment: Have you tried with a newer version of Mule?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.